# Repeat column footer on each page rdlc 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, reportviewer, rdlc

is it possible to have a column on the right end of the matrix table which is repeated on each page and shows alwasy the total sum of all data of the row.

I just was able to do this for the header column but couldn't get it to repeat on each page for other columns.

With best regards,

Helmut

Comment: The `RepeatWith` property sounds like what you need, but setting the table as the data region didn't work for me when I tried it.  You might try experimenting with that, if you haven't already.  I'm also reading that property may not be supported in Forms or PDF export (if it hasn't been added in the latest version), so that would be something to keep in mind as well.  Good luck.